# MySQL: Convert from UTC to Server-Time

Tags: php, mysql, date, utc

I got a little problem: In my Table there are some DATETIME-Fields, where the date is saved as UTC dates.

Now I would like to use this for my where-clause, but mysql should use the saved datetime and convert it from UTC to server-timezone - in this case +2 hours.

How can I do that?

Comment: use date_default_timezone_set('your-timezone'); before add to db

Answer (score 0):

Solution: update the DATETIME values by adding two hours in an update statement.

`UPDATE table_name SET date_time_col = DATE_ADD(date_time_col, INTERVAL 2 HOUR);`  Now all of the values are in the desired local time(two hours ahead of UTC).

Or if you need to keep the values in UTC but only switch to local when querying, perhaps this:
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_ADD(date_time_col, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) = 'input query date';`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

In the meantime I solved it this way:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`date_time_col`,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone) < NOW()
```